# find the class (coset) of a rotation.

Tags: group-theory

> Within the group of bijections of the circle construct a succession of subgroups $G_i$ such that $G_i$ is a subgroup of $G_{i+1}$ and further $|G_i|=i!$."

> find the class (coset) of a rotation.

My try: Basically bijections on circles are roations by negated degree. Also full roation of circle is $360°$. Let say $360°$ is the identity element and  say $G_1=\{360°=e\}$. Now consider $G_2$ which is generated by the rotation $180°$ , that is applied rotation two times to get identity, so $G_2=\{180°,360°\}$. We claim that $G_i$ is generated by a rotation of $360°/i!$. For $i=1$ there is nothing to prove. Suppose it's true for $i=k$ that is $G_{k}$ is generated by a rotation of $ 360°/k!$. We prove that for $i=k-1$. Applying rotation $k$ times we get: $(360°/k!)k=360/(k-1)!$. Thus $G_i$ is generated by the rotation $360°/i!$. Thus $G_{i-1}\subseteq G_i$.

**Finding cosets of $G_i$**:
Consider the group $G_i$ which is generated by a rotation of $360°/i!$ and  with $|G_{i}|=i!$.
As we have constructed a succsession of subgroups so we can take any subgroup of $G_i$ say $G_m$. Let $x\in G_i$ then $x=360°/n!$ for some positive integer $n$. Then $G_mx$ is the right coset of $G_i$.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: "Is my approach correct?" It seems to me that everything is correct.